# Top Level Statement Entry Point Highlighted in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, resharper, .net-5, c#-9.0

I have recently updated Visual Studio 2019 to 16.10, now it is highlighting the top level statement entry point in green:

[image]

If I edit the file then the highlight disappears. It will also sometimes disappear after a short time on it's own but not very consistently.

Selecting the `<top-level-statements-entry-point>` re-highlights the code.

[image]

I do also have ReSharper (2021.1.3) installed but have disabled it and it makes no difference to this highlighting.

I have also tried opening Visual Studio in safemode but it won't even load the project then.

How do I turn this highlighting off (or at least change its colour)?

Comment: I'm not seeing this. What does your csproj file look like? Have you got any other extensions installed?

Comment: The csproj is just the standard when you create a new .net 5 console app: `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is controlled by the "Highlighted Definition" color option under Tools → Options → Environment → Fonts and Colors.  There you can change the color to something different, but it will also change whatever else uses that option (I'm not sure what else might).

I would suggest maybe a lighter blue using the dark theme of Visual Studio:

[image: highlight]

You can mimic turning it off by setting the color to that of the background of Visual Studio.  You can do this by going to the Highlighted Definition color option and for the Item Background control, press the Custom button and type in the following:

- Red: 30
- Green: 30
- Blue: 30
- Hue: 160
- Sat: 0
- Lum: 28

This will leave you with just the outline around the statement (and technically whatever the text foreground color you have set):

[image: outline]

Or, to turn it completely off outright, go to Tools → Options → Text Editor → C# → Advanced → and uncheck the "Highlight references to symbol under cursor" option.

Comment: Ha, you are right, at least now I can control the colour. I am pretty sure it never treated the top level statement as a "Highlighted Definition" before the latest update though.

Comment: So this means that the highlighting can be turned off by un-checking the `Tools`->`Options...`->`Text Editor`->`C#`->`Advanced`->`Highlight references to symbol under cursor` option then.

Comment: @PiersMyers looks like it - but I don't know what else you may lose by turning that off.  I added a way to "mimic" turning it off too.